# Contradiction of electromagnetic theory and ether theory with principles of relativity

Tags: special-relativity, history, aether

What was the contradiction between the electromagnetic theory and relativity that led Einstein to his two postulates?

Also, Einstein thought that if ether existed there would exist an absolute frame of reference which would violate principles of relativity. However, I don't understand how an existence of ether would provide an absolute frame of reference.

Comment: this is very broad.  Have you read something specific on this topic?

Comment: For the contradiction in electromagnetic theory and relativity, let’s take the example of bringing a magnet to a coil or a coil to a magnet. Einstein said both of these situations are the same. However, I have read that other physicists at the time considered these two situations as different.

Comment: I hope you find the question on ether to be specific though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for History of Science and Mathematics SE.

Answer (score 1):

If you read further than the first paragraphs in the [wiki special relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity#Postulates) article

> The constancy of the speed of light was motivated by Maxwell's theory of electromagnetism and the lack of evidence for the [luminiferous ether.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#History)

*Maxwell's equations are consistent* with Lorentz transformations, which in vacuum have the velocity of light constant. *The inconsistency is with Newtonian physics* which needs a medium for the propagation of light. There is no inconsistency with special relativity, as [Lorentz transformations are   inherent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#History) in Maxwell's equations.

> However, I don't understand how an existence of ether would provide an absolute frame of reference.

The wave theory for water or acoustics, for example, needs a medium to propagate on. In complete vacuum there is no medium, and scientists at the time were trying to create one, on which electromagnetic waves would propagate in vacuum.  Vacuum would be the absolute stationary reference for light, the way water is the reference frame for water waves.

The  [Michelson Morley experiment](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/mmhist.html)  demonstrated that there was no ether through which the earth moved around the sun. The experimental demolition of aether made *c* the velocity of light in a complete vacuum.

The constancy of the velocity of light in vacuum and the impossibility of light going faster was, by thinking out of the box, incorporated for all matter by Einstein, giving us the special theory of relativity, which describes all particle experiments accurately, i.e. is validated innumerable times.

> There is conflicting evidence on the extent to which Einstein was influenced by the null result of the Michelson–Morley experiment In any case, the null result of the Michelson–Morley experiment helped the notion of the constancy of the speed of light gain widespread and rapid acceptance.

Comment: “The Michelson Morley experiment demonstrated that there was no ether on which the electromagnetic waves propagated in vacuum, ” The MM experiment shows, that on the surface of the Earth was a spatial isothropy in the plane, perpendicular to the centre of mass. I’m curious, was this experiment done on the top of a tower or mountain?

Comment: he was measuring the speed of the *earth* through the hypthetical aether http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/mmhist.html

Comment: Anna, masses are bending the space, Particles are following geodesic paths. So how much the space is “bend” on the surface of the earth is explorable only it compare it with a measurement away from the surface. Experiments on airplanes are not count, because they move in relation to the earths surface. The Mount Everest is fine or a tower.

Comment: No need for general relativity in this sense, newtonian is a good approxiimation. It is only with GPS ( which btw has confirmed both special and general relativity) that such accurate measurements can be made.http://www.astronomy.ohio-state.edu/~pogge/Ast162/Unit5/gps.html

Comment: A Sagnac interferometer (ring laser) shows that the speed of light varies based on the motion of the interferometer. Also, they allow an observer in an inertial frame to detect their motion without any observation outside their frame. Relativity stumbles when explaining this.

Comment: @Lambda  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagnac_effect#Relativistic_derivation_of_Sagnac_formula   *The Sagnac effect has stimulated a century long debate on its meaning and interpretation,[much of this debate being surprising since the effect is perfectly well understood in the context of special relativity.*

Comment: But the speed of light clearly varies based the motion on the apparatus. The effect is so pronounced and reliable that they are used for navigation in inertial frames. I know SR does its best to make this compatible with SR. But the speed of light is supposed to be independent of inertial frame motion. It should not change when an interferometer is rotated, but it does. Reminds me of Galileo’s comment when the earth’s motion was not consistent with the church. He simply said “It moves”

Comment: @Lambda  rotating frames are not inertial frames, if people have mathematically proven compatibility with SR that is fine with me. SR is continuously checked in experiments and comes out valid. After all the speed of light is smaller in a medium, so why not different  differentially when frames are rotated.